# Is there a tools attribute for ImageView content in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I could not find a *tools* attribute to set an example image in a layout for Android. My assumption is that there is no such thing at the moment, at least no *direct* support.

But I was wondering whether I just did not search well enough or whether there is a workaround for this.

How do you define image placeholders at design time in Android with *tools*?

---

Example of a *tools* attribute for a TextView (i.e. the *tools:text* attribute for text):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_vote_average"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="8.4/10"/>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's just straightforward like for the `TextView`. Just use `tools:src` to set the image.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

Comment: we only use this at the design part right to view it ? I havent used that thats why im asking

Comment: Yes, that is what `tools` is for. I think we're using it all over out project. Helps in a lot of use-cases.

Answer (score 15):

Use this for random real sample images:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

tools:background works for me too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

1. Write `toolNS` or `tools` on the root of your layout XML and 'ALT+ENTER' to complete the name space statement there. Same works with appNS, android NS is by default mentioned if you generate layout using `new-->layout resource`.
2. Many attributes are not documented in the link : [Tools Namespace Attributes](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes), however these are same as those declared with androidNS (android:) for the current view or layout tag.

Happy Coding :-)