# Can I show a sample view when the layout is normally empty & only populated programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout that I normally add `ImageViews` to programmatically, but I'd like to render better previews inside Android Studio when looking at layouts.

I can't use `tools:src` [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050241/is-there-a-tools-attribute-for-imageview-content-in-android) because I don't have any ImageView at all in the XML until runtime.

As a really naive approach, this works visually in Android Studio:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include tools:layout="@layout/some_sample_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If `@layout/some_sample_layout` is then *another* `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But while it displays OK in Android Studio, it fails to compile:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> main_layout.xml: Error: ERROR: [44 68 44 68 25] must include a layout file:///main_layout.xml
```

Ideally I think that I'm looking for:

- some way to add an ImageView directly to the main `LinearLayout` but mark the whole view as "ignore unless tools" or
- to be able to "swap" in the body of the LinearLayout somehow.

Is this possible with tools at the moment?

Comment: Why can't you change the image using programmatically in the `ImageView`, or else you can use a static layout and inflate them at the time you need

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Sorry if I wasn't clear — the `ImageView`s don't exist in the XML, they're populated at runtime from Java code. What I'm looking for is a way to preview how the layout would look from design mode in Android Studio. That is, the equivalent of `tools:listitem="…"` functionality, except I want to use it for `LinearLayout` rather than `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Why not use `ViewFlipper`?

Comment: I would look at a custom view that behaves differently based upon the value of `isInEditMode()`. If in edit mode, it inflates to look however you want it to and, if not in edit mode, shrinks to nothing or maybe it can even remove itself from the layout (a thought.) A "tools" solution would be better, though.

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking to change my production code as little as possible (as its legacy code). @MartinZeitler, not sure what a ViewFlipper solution would look like here — isn't it a tool for animating through views?

Comment: @Cheticamp interesting, might take a look in that direction.

Comment: @anotherdave As the name might suggest, it flips (switches) two child views... in the preview you then can display the one or the other. At run-time this needs to be switched programmatically; alike this you don't have much useless nesting; one `ViewFlipper` with two `include` (which both can be used as `tools:layout`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cleanest and most universal approach for displaying dynamically inflated views in AS designer would be to use `<include />` tag, quite similar as in your example.

Our `<include />` tag must have `layout` property, to make the app buildable. We can omit it by attaching dummy layout with `<merge />` root. Because it has no children, no views will be inflated.

**Universal `lt_merge_empty.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <!--
        Empty merge tag, so we can use <include/> to show dynamically inflated layouts in designer windows
        For example:

        <include
                tools:layout="@layout/your_inflated_layout"
                layout="@layout/lt_merge_empty"
                />
    -->

</merge>
```

Then use it in your layout:

```
<include
        tools:layout="@layout/your_inflated_layout"
        layout="@layout/lt_merge_empty"
        />
```

**Please note:** for some reason, `tools:layout` must be placed above `layout` property, otherwise it won't be rendered.

Edit: This approach is more universal than [@Sina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331853/3516279)'s one bacause usually you will want to display the exact layout that you are dynamically inflating, so obviously you can't change its `android:visibility` to `gone`.

Comment: If you look carefully it is the included layout(the one used to better design and understand the main layout effects in android studio) that has a GONE visibility not the main layout.

Comment: Requiring `tools:layout` before `layout` looks like a bug to me. You may want to consider reporting it. Doing a code reformat in AS will place `layout` before `tools:layout` so it will break. Use of the `merge` tag in this way is exceptional and doesn't pollute the on-device layout.

Comment: A workaround for the sort order issue is to change how AS sorts XML attributes. In Windows, go to File->Settings->Code Style->XML and add the following rule _attribute/name: .*:layout/namespace: http ://schemas.android.com/tools_ somewhere above the rule _attribute/name: .*/namespace: ^$_ to make `tools:layout` sort before `layout`.

Comment: Really like the fact that this isn't polluting what gets sent to the device.

Answer (score 1):

You must include a layout so include it but set its visibility to gone or set ImageView sizes to zero while having what you like with tools attributes. Here I've done both.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/some_sample_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:layout_width="100dp"
        tools:layout_height="100dp"
        tools:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
</LinearLayout>
```